# programmatically add hyperlink to listitem

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to have the following HTML programmatically:

```
<ul><li><a href="#"></a></li></ul>
```

I can add `<li>` to `<ul>`. But `<a>` to `<li>` is not possible.

My code:

```
    BulletedList ul = new BulletedList();    
    ListItem li = new ListItem();    
    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
    ul.Items.Add(li);
    // li has no property Controls or Items
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [BulletedList, how to set link in ListItem](http://forums.asp.net/post/2869418.aspx), use the [DisplayMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.displaymode.aspx).

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList6" runat="Server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Los Angeles" Value="http://www.Los Angeles.aspx"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Atlanta" Value="http://wwwAtlanta.aspx"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="San Francisco" Value="http://www.San Francisco.aspx"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Or in your code:

```
BulletedList ul = new BulletedList();
ul.DisplayMode = BulletedListDisplayMode.HyperLink;
ListItem li = new ListItem();
ul.Items.Add(li);
```

Comment: +1 for good answer.  You just have to be sure to set the Text and Value on the ListItem, or the link will go nowhere (without a Value) or be invisible (without Text).

Comment: @Jeff: Of course the ListItem values will need to be set, as in the first example. The second sample code just matched Ozkan's format that omitted the values for brevity.

Answer (score 5):

Just try this way

place a `asp:Literal` in your `.aspx` page

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrInfo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and in the backend code

```
  ltrInfo.Text = "<ul>";
  ltrInfo.Text += "<li><a href='page1.aspx'>Link one</a></li>";
  ltrInfo.Text += "<li><a href='page2.aspx'>Link Two </a></li>";
  ltrInfo.Text += "</ul>";
```

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: Much nicer solution because it also gives the opportunity to include 'onclick' actions and the fully range of anchor tag magic.

Answer (score 1):

Your list item 'li' has the properties of 'Text' and 'Value'.

You will need to create the link manually, similar to the following:

```
string link = "<a href=\"#\">link text</a>";
```

and set the 'Text' of the ListItem to the string.

If this is something you do often, it may be worth creating a new class that inherits from ListItem that accepts two parameters in it's constructor (url and text) and automates the creation of the link.

Edit: As indicated by another answer, you may also want to use the BulletedList class's DisplayMode of 'Hyperlink'.  If you take this route, you can use the ListItem's 'Value' property to specify the URL the link should go to, and the 'Text' property to specify the link text.

Comment: This is not working: I get this in my website:
`<li>&lt;a href="#"&gt;link text&lt;/a&gt;</li>`

Comment: @Ozkan: That is correct, this solution won't work since the value will be HTML escaped, and that particular .Net control doesn't have the HtmlEncode property to turn that off. Go with the DisplayMode setting (see my Answer), or drop the BulletedList and use a ListView or Literals instead.