# Adding Hyperlinks dynamically

Tags: c#, webforms

I want a page where hyperlinks are added o the page dynamically. Here is my code

```
<div class="md-content" id="divPopup"  runat="server">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />    
    </div>    

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="label_wrap_docu">
            <asp:Label runat="server">Link Title</asp:Label></div>    
        <div class="text_feild_wrap_docu">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitle"></asp:TextBox></div>
        <div class="label_wrap_docu">
            <asp:Label runat="server">Link URL</asp:Label></div>    
        <div class="text_feild_wrap_docu">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUrl"></asp:TextBox></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="modal-footer">    
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
               HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
                hyp.Text = txtTitle.Text;
                hyp.NavigateUrl = txtTitle.Text;
                Page.Controls.Add(hyp);                    
        }
```

It is working.But one problem is that the old item is replaced by new item. It does not form a list.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I hope it will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998058/programmatically-add-hyperlink-to-listitem

Answer (score 1):

you can add like this:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList6" runat="Server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
```

```
ListItem li = new ListItem();
li.Text="dynamichyperlink";
li.Value="www.google.com"
BulletedList6.Items.Add(li);
```

Comment: Thank You. but I want to create it dynamically, not manually.

Comment: @AnjithaS.Nair you have to declare a `Panel` or some other control in which you would add Hyperlinks

Above code contains dynamic addition see the last lines

Comment: Thank you so uch.. It is working.. Great.. :) @

Dot_NET Pro

Comment: @AnjithaS.Nair Glad it helped, you can mark as answer my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Panel in your page, then in code add HyperLink instances to it's controls.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
// C#
HyperLink hyperLink = new HyperLink();
// Fill in your hyperlink details
panel.Controls.Add(hyperlink);
```

Comment: @AnjithaS.Nair my code, is a list actually. see the last 4 lines